# Inorder to avoid redundancy in CSS code in an Angular App among the various parent child components, what solution is possible?

Tags: css, angular, redundancy

I am working on an Angular application that has multiple parent and child components. Now from the point of view of code optimization and performance, in parent and child CSS files many classes and other CSS attributes are redundant. I require suggestions through which this code redundancy can be avoided in CSS files across different components and code reusability in CSS files can be established.

Comment: If you use classes with the same CSS rules across many components, you might want to consider making some of them global instead -> Put those classes inside of `styles.css`

Comment: People also tend to use CSS libraries (like material, bootstrap, etc)  to reduce the need to write CSS.

Comment: I have been using Angular Material UI, but still redundant code is present in different CSS files of the parent-child component.